# advance use of str replace function

Tags: php

**Example Code**

```
$str = "some text <cs> some text </cs> some text <cs> some text </cs> some text <cs> some text </cs>";
$str = str_replace("<cs>", <textarea id="codeBlock">, $str);
$str = str_replace("</cs>", </textarea>, $str);
```

Now the problem is that it converts all the `<cs>` into `<textarea id="codeBlock">` and what i want is that first `<cs>` in the `$str` should get `id="codeBlock-1"` second would get `id="codeBlock-2"` and so on.

Comment: `str_replace` is just a simple replace of a string. For something like this you would likely need to use [preg_replace_callback](https://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to return a dynamic value based on the number of replacements done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `preg_replace_callback()`. It calls a function to get the replacement string, and this function can increment a variable.

```
$num = 0;
$str = "some text <cs> some text </cs> some text <cs> some text </cs> some text <cs> some text </cs>";
$str = preg_replace_callback('/<cs>/', function($match) use (&$num) {
    $num++;
    return "<textarea id='codeBlock-$num'>";
}, $str);
$str = str_replace("</cs>", "</textarea>", $str);
echo $str;
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/dg68G3)

Comment: Perfect, Thanks.